# How to interpret the drastic change in value after adding an interaction term?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, effects, interaction

I've read other similar threads, but their methods and design differs too much from mine.

Im calculating a multilevel model (mixed effects) with a two level hierarchy (Level 1 :individual sessions , Level 2: Participants) and as soon as I add the interaction term between Added Treatment component 1 Yes/No & added Treatment component 2 Yes/No the beta values for the individual Predictors (Component 1 & 2) go negative and change in value, while the Interaction term is positive.

Here is the Output of my fixed effects before adding the Interaction Term

```
                (Intercept): 24.046430  2.329687 536 10.321743  0.0000
Added component 1 : 2.494618  2.668156 (SE)  59 (DF)  0.934959(t-value)  0.3536 (p)
Added component 2 : 2.914177  2.664200(SE)   59 (DF)  1.093828(t-value)  0.2785 (p)
```

and here after adding the Interaction Term:

```
(Intercept)                                   25.621801  2.673329 536  9.584229  0.0000
Added component 1                    -0.485001  3.676817 (SE)  58 (DF) -0.131908 (t-value)  0.8955 (p)
Added component 2                    -0.358369  3.853397 (SE)  58 (DF) -0.093001 (t-value)  0.9262 (p)
Component 1: Component 2       6.156257  5.285248 (SE)  58 (DF)  1.164800 (t-value)  0.2489 (p)
```

It looks to me like there is an effect of interaction which just not become significant and the values of the individual predictors seem to resemble the initial value minus the value of the Interaction + some additional Change.
But im puzzled about how to interpret the Result....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of an interaction terms changes the model completely so it expected that the parameter estimates will change.

The interaction itself tells you how the "effect" of one variable changes depending on the level of the other.

The main effects have a different interpretation in the presence of an interaction. When a variable is involved in an interaction, it's main effect is interpreted as conditional on the other variable that it is interacted with being zero (or at it's reference level in the case of a categorical variable). The improve interpretation numeric variables are often centred at their mean so that the interpretation is then conditional on the variable being at it's mean rather than zero (eg in the case of some variable were zero makes no sense such as the height or weight or a person.)